# Unboundid LDAP domain attributes

Tags: attributes, passwords, ldap, dns

I need to evaluate an user's password expiration time against an Active Directory.
I'm using Android and Unboundid sdk. I can successfully connect to server using this code

```
final SocketFactory _socket_factory;
final SSLUtil _ssl_util = new SSLUtil(new TrustAllTrustManager());

try {               
  _socket_factory = _ssl_util.createSSLSocketFactory();             
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "*** Unable to initialize ssl", e);
  return null;              
}

LDAPConnectionOptions _ldap_connection_options = new LDAPConnectionOptions();
_ldap_connection_options.setAutoReconnect(true);
_ldap_connection_options.setConnectTimeoutMillis(30000);
_ldap_connection_options.setFollowReferrals(false);
_ldap_connection_options.setMaxMessageSize(1024*1024);

LDAPConnection _ldap_connection = new LDAPConnection(_socket_factory, _ldap_connection_options, _host, _port);

BindRequest _bind_request = new SimpleBindRequest(_username, _password);
BindResult _bind_result = _ldap_connection.bind(_bind_request);
```

I retreive user attributes using a search

```
Filter _filter = Filter.create("(userPrincipalName=lorenzoff)");
SearchRequest _search_request = new SearchRequest(_server._base_dn, SearchScope.SUB, _filter);
```

But how can I read the domain's attribute '*maxPwdAge*'? I can see it in among the domain attributes...

[image]

I need it to evaluate the remaining days until user's password expires.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found a solution. the idea is simple you have to access the base DN and get that attribute:

```
SearchRequest _search_request = new SearchRequest(_server._base_dn, 
      SearchScope.BASE, "(objectClass=*)","maxPwdAge");
```

with this you should get the result with that attribute, if you get `SearchRequest.ALL_USER_ATTRIBUTES` you will have all the attributes shown on your screenshot.

That attribute is common for all users, the next thing you need to do is to search your specific user as you where doing before an get the attribute `pwdLastSet`, as you would expect it has the timestamp of the last time the user changed his password.

now is simple, you need to find the expiration date with the last time the user change it, and the password age

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If `maxPwdAge` is an "operational" attribute, it must be explicitly requested as part of your search request. "User" attributes are returned (as permissions permit), but "operational" attributes must be explicitly requested. To request `maxPwdAge` create your request as follows:

```
SearchRequest _search_request = new SearchRequest(_server._base_dn, 
      SearchScope.SUB, _filter,"maxPwdAge");
```

The `SeachRequest` constructor actually accepts a variable length list of attribute types also:

```
SearchRequest _search_request = new SearchRequest(_server._base_dn, 
     SearchScope.SUB,_filter,"maxPwdAge","minPwdAge",
     SearchRequest.ALL_USER_ATTRIBUTES);
```

requests `maxPwdAge`, `minPwdAge`, and all other user attributes. To request all operational attributes, use `SearchRequest.ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: Hi terry, thanks for your reply. I've tryed all your suggestions but none works. Using 'the first', it returns an entry without any attributes (SearchResultEntry(dn='CN=OlissoApp,OU=Utenti IT-Lab,DC=IT-Lab,DC=local', messageID=2, attributes={}, controls={})), using 'the second' it returns the same attributes array that i've seen till now, but WITHOUT the 'maxPwdAge' attribute. Requesting ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES it returns an empty attribute list one more...

Comment: As said, i see maxPwdAge and minPwdAge inspecting the domain attributes, not on the single user. Telling 'inspecting', i intend viewing the properties of the domain through a Windows gui, nothing more. So the question: having a valid LDAPConnection, how can i get the entire domain's attributes and not for the single user? In other words, how can i hava a SerchResultEntry relative to the domain?